# Why React synthetic event.charCode is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have requirement where I need to chain the invoking of functions in the synthetic events of react.What I have done is as follows

`<textarea onKeyDown={(event) => {this.getEvent(); this.getSelectedWord();}}></textarea>`

When I console the event parameter inside the getEvent method, there is no keyCode or charCode properties.I need to perform an action on enter key event.Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Do you mean when you press any key, you are not finding any keyCode for the key pressed inside onKeyDown handler?

Comment: Try to call `this.getSelectedWord` inside the `getEvent()` at the end,

Comment: @nitesh yes i dont find any keycode